# Difference between the table designs?

Tags: mysql, performance, database-design

Table schema is like:

Applications:

```
applicationid(pk)  
userid(pk) 
applicationname
```

Services:

```
serviceid(pk) 
userid(pk) 
applicationid
servicename
servicetype 
version 
modifieddate
```

I have to write a query to filter all the records for a particular user for a particular applciation. 
userid will have one value 'common', in which case all users will access it and this common record will have version '1'.
If the user 'a' edits the record 'common', then the edited information will be inserted as new record with userid 'a' and version '2'.
In this case,while filtering, I have to show, not the 'common' record, but the user's record with version '2'.
applicationid field will be 'null' for services which does not correspond to any applications, they will be called external services.

With the above data model, I cannot write a filter query that will use the index instead of range.

EDIT:
I have to filter all the records in a particular application of a particular user. We have to consider the above stated points on version and userid while filtering. So, the filtering constraint is becoming too complex.

Applications table is used because I have to display the applciation name in case the applicationid is not null[If the service corresponds to an application].

say, the query becomes like,

```
select ser.*,app.applicationname
from services ser
left join applications app
on ser.userid = app.userid and ser.applicationid = app.applicationid
where (ser.userid = 'user1' OR ser.userid = 'common')
AND (ser.applicationid = 'appid1' OR ser.applicationid IS NULL)
AND (ser.modifieddate < '9999-01-01 00:00:00' OR (ser.modifieddate = '9999-01-01 00:00:00' AND ser.serviceid > ' \n'))
AND ser.version = (select max(ser1.version) 
                     from services ser1
                     where (ser1.userid = 'user1' OR ser1.userid = 'common')
                     AND (ser1.applicationid = 'appid1' OR ser1.applicationid IS NULL)
                     AND ser1.servicename = ser.servicename)
ORDER BY ser.modifieddate,ser.serviceid
LIMIT 0,50
```

But the performance is poor with this query. I want to optimise it. It takes about 2s when the subquery and join uses the indexes **(applicationid,servicename)** and **(userid,applicationid)**. But whatever I do, I cannot make the outer query take up any index. Any suggestions?

Will you please help me

1. To arrive at a better query plan?
2. Or to redesign the table?

Comment: the services table DDL is not clear.Please elaborate ur requirement

Comment: I have added some more detail.. Hope this helps a better understanding.. :)

Answer (score 1):

I partitioned the services table based on the data I am going to store as shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE `app_ws_common` (                                                                                                     
          `serviceid` varchar(16) NOT NULL,                                                                                             
          `applicationid` varchar(16) default NULL,                                                                                     
          `modifieddate` date default NULL,                                                                                             
          `version` decimal(1,0) default NULL,                                                                                          
          `servicename` varchar(20) default NULL,                                                                                       
          `userid` varchar(128) NOT NULL,                                                                                             
          PRIMARY KEY  (`serviceid`,`userid`),                                                                                        
          KEY `table1_isv_fk` (`applicationid`,`userid`),                                                                             
          CONSTRAINT `table1_isv_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`applicationid`, `userid`) REFERENCES `applications` (`applicationid`, `userid`)  
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1



 CREATE TABLE `app_ws_user` (                                                                                                     
           `serviceid` varchar(16) NOT NULL,                                                                                              
           `userid` varchar(128) NOT NULL,                                                                                              
           `applicationid` varchar(16) default NULL,                                                                                      
           `modifieddate` date default NULL,                                                                                              
           `version` decimal(1,0) default NULL,                                                                                           
           `servicename` varchar(20) default NULL,                                                                                        
           PRIMARY KEY  (`serviceid`,`userid`),                                                                                         
           KEY `FK_app_ws_user` (`applicationid`,`userid`),                                                                             

           CONSTRAINT `FK_app_ws_user` FOREIGN KEY (`applicationid`, `userid`) REFERENCES `applications` (`applicationid`, `userid`)  
         ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


CREATE TABLE `applications` (                  
            `applicationid` varchar(16) NOT NULL,        
            `userid` varchar(128) NOT NULL,            
            `applicationname` varchar(30) default NULL,  
            PRIMARY KEY  (`applicationid`,`userid`)    
          ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1  

 CREATE TABLE `external_ws_common` (           
               `serviceid` varchar(16) NOT NULL,        
               `modifieddate` date default NULL,        
               `version` decimal(1,0) default NULL,     
               `servicename` varchar(20) default NULL,  
               PRIMARY KEY  (`serviceid`)               
             ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1  


CREATE TABLE `external_ws_user` (            
                `serviceid` varchar(16) NOT NULL,          
                `userid` varchar(128) NOT NULL,          
                `applicationid` varchar(16) default NULL,  
                `modifieddate` date default NULL,          
                `version` decimal(1,0) default NULL,       
                `servicename` varchar(20) default NULL,    
                PRIMARY KEY  (`serviceid`,`userid`)      
              ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Here:

**app_ws_common** table contains all the application related services that are common to all users

**app_ws_user** table contains all the application related services created by a particular user and editted from its common version.

**applications** table will contain the list of applications and the corresponding user.

**external_ws_common** table will contain the list of services independent of all applications and common to all users.

**external_ws_user** table will contain the list of services that does not correspond to any application and created or edited from 'common' version of external service, by a user.

Now, I have to retrieve all application related services from table app_ws_user and all the services from table app_ws_common ,when they do not have the editted version for that particular user in app_ws_user table.

How can I write a query for this efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

From what you have written I would approach the data model by creating the following tables:

- user (holds a list of users)
- application (holds a list of applications)
- applicationVersion (holds a list of application versions mapped to userId)
- service (holds a list of services)
- serviceApplicatioVersion (holds which version of which application is mapped to which service)

You may even want to introduce a serviceVersion table and then map a version of a service to versions of applications. I can't tell from what you have written whether a service has a version or an application does. Anyway, here is some DDL and noddy example data to illustrate what I mean:

```
create table user
(id int unsigned not null primary key auto_increment,
userName varchar(50) not null,
unique key userUIdx (userName));

create table application
(id int unsigned not null primary key auto_increment,
applicationName varchar(50) not null,
unique key applicationUIdx1 (applicationName));

create table applicationVersion
(id int unsigned not null primary key auto_increment,
applicationId int unsigned not null,
version decimal(10,2) unsigned not null default 1.0,
userId int unsigned not null,
modifiedDate timestamp,
unique key applicationVersionUIdx1 (applicationId,version),
constraint `fk_applicationVersion_user1` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
constraint `fk_applicationVersion_application1` FOREIGN KEY (`applicationId`) REFERENCES `application` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);

create table service
(id int unsigned not null primary key auto_increment,
serviceName varchar(50) not null,
serviceType varchar(50) not null,
unique key serviceUIdx1 (serviceName));

create table serviceApplicationVersion
(id int unsigned not null primary key auto_increment,
applicationVersionId int unsigned not null,
serviceId int unsigned not null,
modifiedDate timestamp,
unique key serviceApplicationVersionUIdx1 (applicationVersionId,serviceId),
constraint `fk_serviceApplicationVersion_applicationVersion1` FOREIGN KEY (`applicationVersionId`) REFERENCES `applicationVersion` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
constraint `fk_serviceApplicationVersion_service1` FOREIGN KEY (`serviceId`) REFERENCES `service` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);

insert into user (userName) values ('common');
insert into user (userName) values ('User A');
insert into user (userName) values ('User B');

insert into application (applicationName) values ('App 1');
insert into application (applicationName) values ('App 2');

insert into applicationVersion (applicationId,version,userId) values (
(select id from application where applicationName = 'App 1'),
1.0,
(select id from user where userName = 'common')
);

insert into applicationVersion (applicationId,version,userId) values (
(select id from application where applicationName = 'App 1'),
2.0,
(select id from user where userName = 'User A')
);

insert into service (serviceName, serviceType) values ('Service 1','Service with apps');
insert into service (serviceName, serviceType) values ('Service 2','Service with no apps');

insert into serviceApplicationVersion (applicationVersionId,serviceId) values (
(select av.id from applicationVersion av inner join application a on a.id = av.applicationId where a.applicationName = 'App 1' and av.version = 2.0),
(select id from service where serviceName = 'Service 1')
);

-- Query to select services,applications and versions in those services and users
select s.serviceName,
a.applicationName,
av.version,
u.userName
from user u
inner join applicationVersion av on av.userId = u.id
inner join serviceApplicationVersion sav on sav.applicationVersionId = av.id
inner join application a on av.applicationId = a.id
inner join service s on s.id = sav.serviceId
where userName = 'User A';
```

You'll probably have to tweak it a great deal depending on what you want but hopefully it'll get you going in the right direction.

Comment: @Tom-Thanks for the input :) The version is for services. So, I can create a table 'ServiceVersion[serviceid,userid,version]' , which will keep track of the version of a service for a particular user.If this table does not have any entry for a particular user, I can take the 'common' userid's record,in case, two records exists, one with 'Common' and one with userid 'a'. I will analyze how this works and simplifies my query.